# How do I implement the holder.itemView.setOnClickListener from the UserAdapter in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-studio-3.0

I apologize about the title, I wasn't sure how to phrase my question correctly.

I have a UserAdapter, a Chatlist and a Searchfragment and the user_item. The problem is, the three Click Listeners "Follow", "Go to user's profile" and "Go to chatActivity" are available on both Fragments.

I want, that the "Go to user's profile" click listener only work in the Searchfragment but not in the Chatlistfragment and also hide the "follow/following" button on the Chatlistfragment. Right now they work on both fragments.

I'll appreciate any help!

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<User> mUsers;
private boolean isFragment;

private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

String theLastMessage;

public UserAdapter(Context context, List<User> users, boolean isFragment) {
    mContext = context;
    mUsers = users;
    this.isFragment = isFragment;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public UserAdapter.ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.user_item, parent, false);
    return new UserAdapter.ImageViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final UserAdapter.ImageViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    final User user = mUsers.get(position);
    holder.btn_follow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    isFollowing(user.getId(), holder.btn_follow);

    holder.username.setText(user.getUsername());
    holder.fullname.setText(user.getFullname());
    Glide.with(mContext).load(user.getImage()).into(holder.image_profile);

    // Go to clicked user's profile
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isFragment) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("profileid", user.getId());
                editor.apply();

                ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ProfileFragment()).commit();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("publisherid", user.getId());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    // Start chatActivity with clicked user
    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MessageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("userid", user.getId());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }
    });

    // Click handler: User can un / follow by clicking on the button
    holder.btn_follow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (holder.btn_follow.getText().toString().equals("follow")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                        .child("following").child(user.getId()).setValue(true);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(user.getId())
                        .child("followers").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);

                addNotification(user.getId());
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                        .child("following").child(user.getId()).removeValue();
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(user.getId())
                        .child("followers").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            }
        }

    });
}

// ViewHolder holding data of user
public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView username, fullname, last_message;
    public CircleImageView image_profile;
    public Button btn_follow;

    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        fullname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        image_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        btn_follow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.follow_btn);
        last_message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_msg);
    }
}
```

My SearchFragment

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private UserAdapter userAdapter;
    private List<User> userList;

    EditText search_bar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        search_bar = view.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);

        userList = new ArrayList<>();
        userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), userList, true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);

        readUsers();
        search_bar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                searchUsers(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void searchUsers(String s){
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").orderByChild("username")
                .startAt(s)
                .endAt(s+"\uf8ff");

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        userList.add(user);
                }

                userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void readUsers() {

        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (search_bar.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    userList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                        userList.add(user);

                    }

                    userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

My ChatlistFragment

```
public class ChatListFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private UserAdapter userAdapter;
    private List<User> mUsers;
    FirebaseUser fuser;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    private List<Chatlist> usersList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_list, container, false);

        // Init
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.chatList_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        usersList = new ArrayList<>();

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist").child(fuser.getUid());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                usersList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Chatlist chatlist = snapshot.getValue(Chatlist.class);
                    usersList.add(chatlist);
                }

                chatList();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void chatList() {
        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsers.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    for (Chatlist chatlist : usersList) {
                        if (user.getId().equals(chatlist.getId())) {
                            mUsers.add(user);
                        }
                    }
                }
                userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers, true);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

My User_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <!-- Profile Picture -->
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_profile"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile" />

    <!-- Layout: Username, fullname, last message -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_profile"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Benutzername"
            android:textColor="@color/colorProfileFollowPostText"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fullname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_msg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:text="Last message" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Button: Follow -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/follow_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/followbutton"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Folgen"
        android:textColor="@color/colorProfileFollowPostText"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in this case, just having a boolean in the constructor of the adapter will do the job.
Let's say your isFragment boolean is used for this. So follow button visibility just set to GONE if isFragment is true and when clicking on "Go to user's profile" button just do this:

```
if (isFragment)
    return
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give it a try.  :) 

I don't know, if the upvote works since I am new so they are monitored.

Comment: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score, so don't worry, i just hope i helped :)

Comment: Ah okey. Just wanna make sure, people get their upvotes, when I give them. Thanks for the info. Thanks yes :)